# Asynctask Loading multiple times in run time permission

Tags: android, android-asynctask, runtime-permissions

I am beginner in android.Here i am trying to call the particular Async-task after Runtime permission granted in Marshmallow (**NearLocations.execute()**) but if i grant the permission(Allow) my Async-tasks are calling multiple times and progress bar is keep on loading.Suggest me how to solve this issue?

```
public class DashViewScreen extends Fragment implements OnRefreshListener {
    public static final int MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 10; // code you want.
    String[] permissions = new String[] {
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION };
    Location mLocation;
    View v1;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_layout, container, false);
        initialUISetup();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Oncreate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        checkPermission(getActivity());
        return v;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void initialUISetup() {
        //Async task one
        mTask = new Information(v, false);
        mTask.execute();
    }

    private class Information extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Object> {
        private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
        private View v1;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Retrieve Acc", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mTask = null;
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Void... params) {
            AccountInformation results = null;
            results = AppUtil.drex.AccountInformation(v1.getContext());
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            mAccInfo = (AccountInformation) result;
            //Async task two
            mTask = new Messages().execute();
        }
    }

    private boolean checkPermission(Activity act) {
        int result;
        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String p : permissions) {

            result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(act, p);
            if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(p);
            } else {
                if (lastLocation == null) {
                    locationManager = (LocationManager) v.getContext()
                            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

                    gpsLocationListener = createListener(v);
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                            gpsLocationListener);
                }
                //Async three
                new NearLocations(lastLocation, v).execute();
            }
        }
        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {

            requestPermissions(
                    listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded
                            .size()]), MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);

            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
            String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    lastLocation = AppUtil.getMyLastLocation(v.getContext());

                    if (lastLocation == null) {
                        locationManager = (LocationManager) v.getContext()
                                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

                        lastLocation = AppUtil.getBestLocation(v.getContext(),
                                locationManager);

                        gpsLocationListener = createListener(v);
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                                gpsLocationListener);
                    }
                    new NearLocations(lastLocation, v).execute();
                } else {
                    AppUtil.saveBoolToPrefs(getActivity(), "stopPopup", true);
                }
                return;
            }
        }
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions,    grantResults);
    }    
}
```

Comment: You are running your async task every time your asking and cheking permissions, which you have mentioned in your AndroidManifest, please execute your task only once or create only one instance of your NearLocation class and execute it.

Comment: Why you are calling  mTask = new Messages().execute(); on OnPostExecute() have you  checked how many time the onPostExecute() method is getting called

Answer (score 0):

I read you code but I could not understand every thing.
I have a class runs like async task. I prefer use it.

```
public abstract class AsyncTaskSubhi {

Activity activity;
MaterialDialog dialog;
String processName;
public AsyncTaskSubhi(Activity activity, String processName) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.processName=processName;
}


public void onPreExecute() {
    dialog= new MaterialDialog.Builder(activity)
            .title("*****")
            .content(processName+"is running").cancelable(false)
            .progress(true, 0).autoDismiss(false)
            .show();
}

public abstract void doInBackground();

public void execute() {
    try {
         new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (activity != null)
                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            onPreExecute();
                        }
                    });

                doInBackground();

                if (activity != null)
                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            onPostExecute();
                        }
                    });

            }
        }).start();

    }catch (Exception e){
        dialog.dismiss();
    }


}
public void onPostExecute() {
    dialog.dismiss();
    new MaterialDialog.Builder(activity)
            .title("*****")
            .content("OK")
            .positiveText(R.string.ok).show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
for (String p : permissions) {
    result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(act, p);
    if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(p);
    } else {
        if (lastLocation == null) {
             locationManager = (LocationManager) v.getContext()
                                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

             gpsLocationListener = createListener(v);
             locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                                gpsLocationListener);
             }
             //Async three
             //it will be executed PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED is true put log where how many time it is executed
                    new NearLocations(lastLocation, v).execute();
    }
}
```

Try removing this code with

```
for (String p : permissions) {
            result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(act, p);
            if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(p);
            } else {
                if (lastLocation == null) {
                    locationManager = (LocationManager) v.getContext()
                            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

                    gpsLocationListener = createListener(v);
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                            gpsLocationListener);
                }
            }
        }

        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            requestPermissions(
                    listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded
                            .size()]), MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            return false;
        }else {
            new NearLocations(lastLocation, v).execute();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling your AsyncTask.execute():

```
      new NearLocations(lastLocation, v).execute();
```

in a for loop in your checkPermission() method: for every permission which is already granted:

```
        for (String p : permissions) {

        result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(act, p);
        if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(p);
        } else {
            if (lastLocation == null) {
                locationManager = (LocationManager) v.getContext()
                        .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

                gpsLocationListener = createListener(v);
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                        gpsLocationListener);
            }
            //Async three
            new NearLocations(lastLocation, v).execute();
        }
    }
```

Then again calling it in onRequestPermissionsResult() , which is causing multiple calling of AsyncTask.